# How to disable a form resize at design time?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application I am deriving all my forms from a common BaseForm.

Now I need to disable the resizing in the BaseForm so that derived forms are not resizable at design-time.

How to achieve that?

### I need it at design-time

Comment: I think I get you now, I updated my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent users from changing the window/form size when application is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330339/how-can-i-prevent-users-from-changing-the-window-form-size-when-application-is-r)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to work:

**[BaseForm.cs]**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class BaseForm : Form
    {
        public BaseForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.MaximumSize = this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
        }
    }
}
```

**[DerivedForm.cs]**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class DerivedForm : WindowsFormsApplication1.BaseForm
    {
        public DerivedForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

i used

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
```

this make window form as like dialogBox. so dialog boxes are not resizable by user.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

Comment: You can also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849135/winform-inheritance-designer-settings-are-copied-to-derived-form

Comment: There is a place to set this property at design time in the VS designer gui, is that what you are referring to?

Comment: The one I am referring to is making the properties in the base form as read only.

Answer (score 2):

If you go into design view and look in the form's properties menu, there is a `Locked` property, which disables resizing of the form.

**EDIT**

Try setting the `MaximumSize` and `MinimumSize` properties to the same value.

Comment: Oh, I think I get you now. How about setting the MaximumSize and MinimumSize to the same value?